# BBCode vs html, which one save in database?

Tags: php, html, database, bbcode

I have been seen several examples in  internet, when 'they' saved BBCode text in database, and then, at select, every time convert this BBCode to html.

My question is: would be not better convert BBCode to html when saving (just once) in database, and then  select  and show already converted html code? something like this:

```
$_POST['text'] = strip_tags($_POST['text']);
// here, in $_POST['text'] convert BBCode to html code.
// insert table converted $_POST['text'].
```

Is this bad practice? and if yes, why, what issues may cause this?

Comment: BBCode's better because, when the user wants to edit, it would be easy.

Comment: On top of @PraveenKumar's comment, it means that all existing text will render the same if you were to change something about how it's rendered / displayed.

Comment: Thanks, you are right

Comment: As well as storing the BBCode, it may also help to cache the HTML output. But may I suggest ditching BBCode, and allowing the user to enter plain HTML? See http://htmlpurifier.org/comparison

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always save the "rawest" form of the data in the database. This will allow you to produce any presentation format (e.g. HTML, EPUB, PDF, etc.) simply by swapping out the presentation layer.